# How to open or download PDF file in Google Drive inside my application

Tags: c#, pdf, ado.net, google-drive-api

Hi everyone I am trying to create an application (C# Windows Form Application) that can open and/or download PDF files from Google Drive (My drive)

This is a sample way to open a PDF file from my hard disc using Adobe PDF Reader (AxAcroPDF):

```
    private void btn_OpenPDF_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.Filter = "PDF Files (*.pdf)|*.pdf";
        ofd.Title = "Open an PDF file";

        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            apr_OpenPDF.src = ofd.FileName;
        }
    }
```

But what about reading a PDF files from Google Drive ?

Thanks for any help and sorry for my English

Comment: Your tags show ado.net, but your code looks suspiciously like wpf. Have you searched here? There are tons of threads on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

You can open, download and convert files using [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/integrate-open). When a user selects an app from the Open with contextual menu for a Google Doc, Drive redirects the user to the Open URL for the selected application. The redirected request from the user's browser contains this important information in the state parameter:

- The action, set to open.
- The exportIds to use.

Download and convert file content with the [`files.export`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/export) method.

```
var fileId = "1ZdR3L3qP4Bkq8noWLJHSr_iBau0DNT4Kli4SxNc2YEo";
var request = driveService.Files.Export(fileId, "application/pdf");
var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
// Add a handler which will be notified on progress changes.
// It will notify on each chunk download and when the
// download is completed or failed.
request.MediaDownloader.ProgressChanged +=
(IDownloadProgress progress) =>
{
switch(progress.Status)
{
case DownloadStatus.Downloading:
{
Console.WriteLine(progress.BytesDownloaded);
break;
}
case DownloadStatus.Completed:
{
Console.WriteLine("Download complete.");
break;
}
case DownloadStatus.Failed:
{
Console.WriteLine("Download failed.");
break;
}
}
};
request.Download(stream);
```